# How to remotely debug Java (EE) server code in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jakarta-ee, weblogic, remote-debugging

I am working on Java server side code (`Java EE`) using `Eclipse` and run a weblogic server. The code will then be built and deployed into `weblogic` using Ant. Normally, when I make a change, I have to run Ant to build the code and restart weblogic to see the change. Now I cannot just set a check point in source code and run Ant build source code to debug.

Provided I am having weblogic running on localhost:7001, and having my app named my_app. So I will have to go to `localhost:7001/my_app` to see the change.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to remotely debug, but that's only used in truly remote cases when you cannot reproduce the problem locally. For local debugging, you would be much better off by using [Oracle WebLogic Server Tools](https://web.archive.org/web/20150102013737/http://marketplace.eclipse.org:80/content/oracle-weblogic-server-tools-kepler) instead of building with Ant.

These tools will allow you to run and debug your application on WLS straight from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use JPDA with eclipse for remote java machine debugging.Have a look on this link may be this help you.
https://wiki.xnat.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5015004